# Possible physical interface attacks of BMCs on a server

Tags: attacks, hardware

Following from: [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/185826/possible-physical-interface-attacks-on-a-server?noredirect=1#comment364395_185826),

Let's say you have a server at a data centre, but a hacker manages to find a way in and has access to your server. What are the attack possibilities regarding [Baseboard Management Controllers (BMCs)](https://blog.rapid7.com/2013/07/02/a-penetration-testers-guide-to-ipmi/) attacks?

Are there any known attack and defence mechanisms to a system once physical access has been gained?

My server is running Ubuntu 16.04, and I like to perform some attacks myself for educational purposes.

The question is a bit broad, however, I am hoping for practical answers, such as:

```
Look here: https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-5689
```

Comment: *"Are there any known attack and defence mechanisms to a system once physical access has been gained?"* As the adage goes, and as I pointed out in a comment to [your other question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/185962/2138), once the attacker has unrestricted physical access to your computer, it's not your computer anymore.

Comment: Similar post: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/185962/possible-physical-interface-attacks-of-dma-on-a-server